# Trouble with HTML5 form patterns

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I'm programming a little HTML form with pattern included in a  tag where a phone number must be introduced. Problem is I can't make the pattern to work as intended. Even if the desired pattern is introduced it still won't let submit the form. It's pretty obvious there's a problem in the pattern but can't figure out what (seems OK to me, but I'm no good with patterns).

The format to be accepted is XXX-XXXXXX, with X being numbers. 
Here's the code in that `<input>` tag so far:

```
<input type="text" name="phonenum" id="phonenum" maxlength="10" pattern="/^\d{3}-\d{6}$/" required="required">
```

Same pattern is working in an alternate JavaScript validation file. I don't know what must be changed for it to work as a tag pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put the / / marks.
Something like

```
<input type="text" name="phonenum" id="phonenum" maxlength="10" pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{6}" required="required">
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="text" name="phonenum" id="phonenum" maxlength="10" pattern="^\d{3}-\d{6}$">
```

You don't need delimiters, that's all...tested in FF.

Comment: It was THAT easy! Still don't get why I have seen it with delimiters in more than one place, but i'll try to remember not to add them. Many thanks!